# Why is the complex principal square root function defined as it is?

Tags: complex-analysis

The complex principal square root function is defined over the entire complex plane minus the real nonpositive axis, and its image covers the right-half complex plane, that is, the complex plane containing complex numbers with positive real part. Why is that the case?

I understand that the square root function has always two branches and that, if we want to define it as a single-valued function, we need to have a branch cut in its domain. However, the location of the branch cut (hence the image) is totally arbitrary. I see that defining it such that the output always has a positive real part is quite "natural", but there may be problems requiring a different definition, thus changing the intuition for what is natural to define.

Hence, my question is: are there properties of the complex square root function that hold if and/or only if its output is a complex number with positive real part?

Comment: You only "need" a branch cut if you insist on the domain of the square root function being a subset of the complex plane. If you allow Riemann surfaces as a domain then the branch cut issue essentially disappears.

Comment: for a positive real number, square root function is defined as the positive square root

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the Riemann surface is defined using the branch cut, and the location of the branch cut is arbitrary. So are there properties of the complex square root function that are valid if and/or only if one makes the "principal choice" for the branch cut?